# Mouse click on Webelement in a grid

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]

Need to select a row from the grid, the following piece of code I tried.

**Failed**

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(Customerpolicy).click(Customerpolicy).build().perform();
```

**Failed**

```
Action dbClick = builder.doubleClick(Customerpolicy).build();
dbClick.perform();
```

Finally I tried JavascriptExecutor

```
JavascriptExecutor exec = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
exec.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", Customerpolicy);
```

The element got clicked, but the page is not loading, its getting hung, when we perform through code, manual mouse click works perfectly.

Let me know the best solution to select the row.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using `ActionChains` for this operation? Also, what `locator` are you using for `Customerpolicy`?

Comment: @Mark Rowlands - To identify the Webelement WebElement Customerpolicy = driver.findElement(By.id("portfolioForm:portfolioData:0:productValue"));  There is no particular reason for the ActionChains, just looked at couple of examples.

Comment: Maybe try the direct `click()` call on the element? `driver.findElement(By.id("portfolioForm:portfolioData:0:productValue")).click();`

Comment: @Mark Rowlands, driver.findElement(By.id("portfolioForm:portfolioData:0:productValue")).click(); does not perform any action, it did throw any expection too. I tried .submit() too the same results.

Comment: Sorry "did throw any exception" - so it did or didn't? Is that a typo?

Comment: It's a typo, No expection throwed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36090/discussion-between-thirumalai-and-mark-rowlands)

Comment: If no `exception` is being thrown it means that `WebDriver` is clicking that element. The trouble is, the click isn't causing the expected action. Unfortunately, unfamiliarity with your web-app and how its built - I can only suggest that you execute the attached JavaScript that would occur on the click. Maybe that will help.

Comment: @Mark Rowlands - The below piece of code worked when you set the action and then perform the webelemnt.click. Can you please let me know the reason it worked?  Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("portfolioForm:portfolioData:0:policyNumber"))).build().perform();
driver.findElement(By.id("portfolioForm:portfolioData:0:policyNumber")).click();